# save multiple symfony form

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a Collection Form

```
class MyCollectionForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('my_collection[%s]');

    $groups = Doctrine::getTable('QuotaGroup')->findAll(); //existing groups
    foreach ($groups as $i => $group)
    {
        $groupForm = new QuotaGroupForm($group);
        $this->embedForm($i, $groupForm);
    }

    $i++;
    $this->embedForm($i, new QuotaGroupForm(new QuotaGroup())); //new group

    $this->mergePostValidator(new QuotaGroupValidatorSchema());
  }
}
```

In the Save Action I do:

```
$this->form->bind($params);
if($this->form->isValid())
{
   $this->form->save();
}
```

I get an error: Call to undefined method MyCollectionForm::save()

I cant´t find the error because sfForm has a save method...

Comment: Wow, this is really strange! Could you check whether `MyCollectionForm instanceof sfForm`? Did you use copy/paste for everything in your question (including the error message?)

Comment: Not about embedded programming.  Retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sfForm does not have a save method...

You should extend sfFormDoctrine.

```
class MyCollectionForm extends sfFormDoctrine{ ...
```